# npm and node try to insall a version of jest that I cant use

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm a little confused. I have node version 10 and when I try to install jest I get a version that is incompatible with node version 10.

```
npm install jest --save-dev #installs version 28 even tho it will not run
yarn add jest --dev #tells me I need node version 12 or higher
```

I know there are versions of jest I can use with node version 10 so why don't these package managers just resolve this?
I can get past this by specifying version 24:

```
yarn add jest@24 --dev #or can do the same with npm
```

But why do I need to know specific versions that are compatible? Shouldnt the package managers be able to resolve compatible versions of dependacies?

Or is there some fundamental understanding I am missing with node packages?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify version by adding `@1` where 1 is the version you want of a specific package. [reference](https://nodejs.dev/learn/install-an-older-version-of-an-npm-package) / [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install)

using [n](https://github.com/tj/n), I was able to `sudo n 10`, `mkdir test && cd test && npm init -y && npm i jest@27 && yarn run jest` and it failed on `npm i jest@28`.

Comment: I know I can specify a version as I said that's what I did.  My point is why do I have to. Should the package manager not be able to resolve the correct version?

Comment: I'll update my question to make it more clear.